# Automatically stage new files Git

Tags: git, intellij-idea, staging

Here is my problem:

The .idea/ folder is updated each time I make a changes to the code, thus I have to stage it each time I make a change, which is tiring.

I'd like to know if there is a way through Git bash(preferably) or IntelliJ so that it gets staged automatically.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? Normally it is a bad idea to commit .idea or any editor specific files, almost all projects I have worked on, have added those folders to .gitignore file.

Comment: oh, I didn't know that it was common practice, thank you:D

Comment: Since you are using intellij, I can heavily recommend taking a look at this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495--ignore  this makes it a breeze for adding content to your .gitignore files. Give it a shot, thank me later and then support the developer of the plugin if you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we get to the answer... as others have noted, committing IDE-specific files is not usually a good idea.  I'm aware that IDEA stores a lot of configuration in the `.idea` directory, and if you're not using a build tool (like Maven if you're as old school as me, or Gradle if you're into more modern tooling), then it may be that committing these files preserves work you don't want to redo; but I would recommend using an IDE-neutral build tool and committing the corresponding project definition file (e.g. pom for maven, etc.)  Then you can safely remove the `.idea` files and add them to your ignore rules.

But ok, your question is how to make sure changes at a certain path (`.idea/**`) are included in every commit.  Since you prefer a `git bash`-based solution, I would say that an alias or script is your best bet; as long as you use the alias or script instead of regular `git commit`, you can have it `add` the `.idea` directory before the commit.

```
git config alias.ci '!git add :/:.idea && git commit'
```

The changes will still show up as "unstaged" in `git status`.  There's not a lot you can do about that.

Comment: Thank you:D very informative, I'll explore the Maven option, and didn't know about Gradle, so thank you for that too:) if it's not too much to ask could you orient me on how to commit project definition file in Maven? thanks again.

Comment: With maven you'd just commit the `pom.xml` file.  Not really any different than committing any other file (`git add pom.xml` ; `git commit`).  Not sure if there's more to the question than that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I now realize that it was as clear as day. Thank you very much for taking the time to explain it:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

Create a global .gitignore file

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
```

Now open `~/.gitignore_global` to add the folder you want to ignore:

```
echo ".idea/" >> ~/.gitignore
```

Comment: Good practice, but not what OP asked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, there doesn't seem to be another solution beside the ones mentioned here or below, thanks a lot, you too Mark Adelsberger for your comment.